# will_paginate route only works on page > 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, will-paginate

I have the following routes defined:

```
map.resources :categories, :has_many => :downloads
map.resources :downloads, :member => {:go => :get}, :collection => {:tag => :get}
map.connect '/downlods/page/:page', :controller => 'downloads', :action => 'index'
map.connect '/categories/:category_id/downloads/page/:page', :controller => 'downloads', :action => 'index'
```

For some reason, the first page that the will_paginate helper is called on causes links with ?page=2 to be rendered, while subsequent pages have links with /downloads/page/2. Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: show your will_paginate code, please

Answer (score 1):

If you simply declare a route with map.connect, it can be hit and miss as to how it's routed if you do something like:

```
link_to("Next", :page => 2)
```

What you might want to do is name the route and then use it that way:

```
map.downloads_paginated '/downloads/page/:page', :controller => 'downloads', :action => 'index'
```

Then you use the route by name:

```
link_to("Next", downloads_paginated_path(2))
```

These are much more reliable.

As a note, you have '/downlods' in your path instead of '/downloads' but I'm not sure that'd be causing the trouble described.

Comment: `will_paginate( @blah, {:controller => 'downloads'})` specifying the controller explicitly could help as well.